# Can I run Php listen unix socket and backup as tcp

Tags: php

Randomly I can see the following error on my Nginx error logs.

```
connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream
```

Can I make PHP listen primarily under Unix socket and if there any issue use TCP as a backup?

My server is running Ubuntu 20.4, Php7.4, Nginx 1.21.0, and MySQL. This site hosted several WordPress sites,